# Will we tag every sequel?

Tags: discussion, tags

How do we tag sequels?

- Harry potter has 7 chapters, and the 7th is actually divided into 2 parts.
- back to the future, Star Wars, Kill Bill

Don't think I need to add more examples, but really:

Do we tag each sequel?

Or synonymize the sequels to the first part?

Answer (score 4):

It is the current practice to tag films independently. If you enter the tags area and search with the strings "-2" or "-3" you will see examples of films released this way. Generally films in the Star Wars and Harry Potter franchises have distinctive titles. Synonyms are not the best way here.

Comment: Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 1 and Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2  - Do you consider them to have distinct names?

Comment: Yes - But, there's always a specific to break any generalization. This fits best so far.